# Dissolving features by attribute(s)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, dissolve

How to apply ‘statistic_field’ to just one ‘dissolve_field’? 
I have a feature class that I need to dissolve by PageName but also by earliest year in SERVED_YEAR.  So, how to apply MIN to SERVED _YEAR only? What I want to achieve is to have one feature of BK16 with SERVED_YEAR = 2011 (and also BK15 with 2013 etc)

Dissolve_management (in_features, out_feature_class, {dissolve_field}, {statistics_fields}, {multi_part}, {unsplit_lines})

Update: I am just asking here about the valid format of the Dissolve_management tool, and I have got enough information (see comments) to solve the problem. Once/if answers are enabled I will add the answer.

[image: Table extract]

Comment: I would take two steps. First qualify the data, maybe go to the layerproperties and make a definitionquery like SERVED_YEAR=MIN(SERVED_YEAR) and then dissolve.

Comment: @ChrisL I don't think you need to remove it.You can answer your own question and even accept your own answer, as long as this isn't a duplicate question it can only add to the site. Just frame your above comment as an answer.

Comment: This is easier to see in the toolbox dialog as it lays out the parameters and how it lets you select statistics fields. Your question is confusing because it makes it sound like you want to dissolve on two fields (which you can do) when in reality you want to dissolve on one field and apply a min statistic on another. Note that min statistic is highly dependent on your field data type - it looks like you have years stored as integers, so it works. If you had dd/mm/yy strings, it wouldn't. It think the question could be useful in the future with some clarification and posting an actual answer.

Comment: @ChrisW You are totally right. I have created this table some time ago, and now I remember that I have decided to use integer format (for year only) as it is easier to manipulate. You have also answered the other question (one I didn’t ask): my `SERVED_YEAR MIN` is not part of {dissolve_field} it is the {statistic_field}, I thought that statistic field is ‘MIN’ (MAX, FIRST, etc) only – thanks for that. Will try to put all of this in to some sensible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it that is so obvious. I have tried to use brackets but this should look like that:

```
arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features, out_feature_class, "PageName", "SERVED_YEAR MIN","MULTI_PART")
```

So expression I have been looking for was `SERVED_YEAR MIN`.